# Webfrontend for VMM

Tags: web-apps, python

I'm looking for a webfrontend for virtual mail manager [vmm](http://vmm.localdomain.org/).

It must be capable to let users change their own passwords. Also it should be able to add/delete new addresses for a domain when logging in as e.g. postmaster@fqdn.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. If you prefer to hack it by yourself, what are you asking for here? If you won't code it from scratch, then do you prefer it in any language, to make it easier for you to update? Can you pr9ovide more information, please?

Comment: Sorry, missing not ... just corrected

Comment: @frlan Do you have any other requirements then the frontend to support password change? If so, could you state them?

Comment: Just updated the question.